# Repositioning of a UIView after CGAffineRotation

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I'm drawing a map of hexagons inside a UIView and the next step is to give it in isometric view. To do this, I transformed the map using the CGAffineTransform, rotation and scaling, reaching my goal.

Now, if the map becomes bigger, when i rotate it, the lower left corner goes out my screen, this is the frame before and after the transformation:

```
2012-03-07 17:08:06.160 PratoFiorito[941:f803] X: 0.000000 - Y: 0.000000 || Width: 1408.734619 - Height: 1640.000000
2012-03-07 17:08:06.163 PratoFiorito[941:f803] X: -373.523132 - Y: 281.054779 || Width: 2155.781006 - Height: 1077.890503
```

I simply can't understand what is the new point of origin and how I can calculate it to replace the view correctly. Somebody can help me?